# Unable to connect to servers on Minecraft: Pocket Edition 0.8.1

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I have been trying to connect to a couple of online servers on Minecraft: Pocket Edition. Every time I try connecting to a server, it always says "locating server" and tells me it could not connect. It used to work well, until a couple of weeks ago it stopped and I could not get it to work.

I have deleted and re-downloaded it a couple of times now and have check all the settings on the app and my phone (including location services) and could not find the problem. And yes, I am using the right server name and IP address (in the external setting) because I used to be avle to connect to these exact servers and now I cannot.

I have an iPhone 4 and Minecraft PE v0.8.1, and I also play on WiFi.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: The servers could be down. Or your WiFi network is not working.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have you checked if they have their local server multiplayer on? You can only join if they do.